# Magento Currency Drop Down and Currency Symbols

Tags: currency, design

I am new to magento..as per my design I need to change the currency drop down to a Euro and Dollar Symbols or Images which I had created. So I would like to know how I could go for this? I managed to change the language to Country flags but stuck with this currency issue. Please share a light on this.

I also wanted to know how to replace "Add to wishlist" and "Add to Compare" and replace it with the images or icons created by me. Please guide me in this regard and also how to bring "email a friend" as an image or icon in the row of "Add to wishlist" ?
[image]
[image]
Thanks

Kris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Themes template/directory/currency.phtml change the code to this (this is based on the RWD theme):

```
<?php
/**
 * Currency switcher
 *
 * @see Mage_Directory_Block_Currency
 */
?>
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>        
<div class="currency-switcher">
        <label for="select-currency"><?php echo $this->__('Your Currency:') ?></label>

        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): 

            // gets the currency symbol for each currency
            $symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol();
        ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>" class="<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected <?php endif; ?>">
            <?php echo $symbol; ?>
        </a>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will look like this:
[image]

As you can see the magic is done with this line after the `foreach` statement:

```
$symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
```

or now:

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol();
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you wish to show images for each currency, there are a couple of ways to do it.

Use CSS and background-images by adding the `$_code` to the a tag class:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): 

    // gets the currency symbol for each currency
    $symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol();
?>

<a href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>" class="<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected <?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_code; ?>">
    <?php echo $symbol; ?>
</a>
```

Then define your css (or in this case scss - sass):

```
.currency-switcher {

    .a { // define all a tags
            display: block;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;           
        }

    // now define the background image for each currency
    .USD {
        background-image: url('path-to-your-dollar-image') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    }

    // now define the rest ...

}
```

The other method would be to directly output the images again using the `$_code` value - so your images would have to be named correctly eg:

`currency_USD.png` and `currency_GBP.png` etc .. and edit your code as such:

```
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): 
        // define the image
        $currency_image = 'path/to/your/image/currency_' . $_code . '.png';
    ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>" class="<?php if($_code==$this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?> selected <?php endif; ?>">
        <?php echo $currency_image; ?>
    </a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I need to remove the drop down and replace with Symbols or Images I have created for the same. I don't need drop down as the client doesn't like it..

Comment: I've edited my answer. The class `selected` is output for the currently active currency. Surely you will manage to style the rest. =)

Comment: Thank you very much....Jam.... I couldn't vote you up because I don't have enough points to do so. Any way I am expressing my gratitude towards you for this amazing help...Thanks once again!!!

Comment: With your permission I am disturbing you for once again...Suppose I need to change the symbols into Icons..What steps we need to take? Please guide me...Thanks

Comment: I've edited my code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot......I don't know how to express my gratitude ....Really really thanks......May the God bless you....

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help and hopefully some of these basics will come in handy for you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your edit - please also edit your title to make it easier to find for people since its now 2 different questions.

Now how to do what you want with the wishlist and add to compare links ... You may already have seperate css classes around 'Auf den Wunschzettel' and 'Auf die Vergleichsliste'.

The path for the template file is (based on RWD theme) `/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml` - in this you can see that classes are given as `link-wishlist` and `link-compare`.

You can either edit your template to output the images directly or simply use css image replacement techniques to replace the text with an image - eg: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageReplacement/

Comment: Sorry for late reply....Thanks for your help and support.....let me try this....

Comment: I just tried But I couldn't get the result. When I called the images from CSS I am getting both Image and Text in the front end and only the portion of Image too.                                                            CODE:                                                                                                .link-wishlist { background:url(../images/wishlist.jpg) no-repeat width:32 height:32; text-indent: -9999px; color:#dc6809 !important; font-weight:bold; }

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: I already got solution and it is working fine...Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The code is as below, however the image seems like a broken link. Any help?

```
<?php if ($block->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<?php $currencies = $block->getCurrencies(); ?>
<?php $currentCurrencyCode = $block->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>
<?php $id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : '' ?>
<div class="switcher currency switcher-currency" id="switcher-currency<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($id) ?>">
    <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Currency')) ?></span></strong>
    <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
        <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
             id="switcher-currency-trigger<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($id) ?>"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
             data-toggle="dropdown"
             data-trigger-keypress-button="true">
            <strong class="language-<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentCurrencyCode()) ?>">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($currentCurrencyCode) ?> - <?= @$block->escapeHtml($currencies[$currentCurrencyCode]) ?></span>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown">
            <?php foreach ($currencies as $_code => $_name): ?>
                <?php if ($_code != $currentCurrencyCode): ?>
                    <li class="currency-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_code) ?> switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSwitchCurrencyPostData($_code) ?>'><?= $block->escapeHtml($_code) ?> - <?= $block->escapeHtml($_name) ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```